# Form submit after jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I have a form with jquery validation. If i clicked submit button, it will trigger jquery validation, if there is no error, i would like it to continue with normal submit procudure.(run the  form action="process.php"...). But when I click submit button and there is no error, it does nothing.

Here is my simple html form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
    <input type ="submit" id="ok" name="ok" />
    <div class='error_message'></div>
</form>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name').focus(); 
    $('#ok').click(function(){
        var name = $('#name'); 
        var error_message = $('.error_message'); 
        if (name.val() == '') { 
            name.focus();
            error_message.html('Name is required!');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Consider using jquery-validation and ajax-form-submit plugins together.

Comment: my form also has input=file and ajax would not work for this case wouldn't it?

Comment: it works. you need to do a post request with multi part form data header :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conditions resulted in the click handler on the submit button result in the event being stopped. Remove the `else` block:

```
$('#ok').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name'); 
    var error_message = $('.error_message'); 
    if (name.val() == '') { 
        title.focus();
        error_message.html('Name is required!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or better yet, hook to the `submit` event of the form:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var error_message = $('.error_message'); 
    if ($('#name').val() == '') { 
        title.focus();
        error_message.html('Name is required!');
        e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    }
});
```

Also, `title` and `error_message` do not appear to be defined in your code. I assume they are declared somewhere else within scope.

Comment: `$('form').submit(function(e)`. The 'form' is name of the form or id of the form?

Comment: Form relates to the form element

Comment: i tried to hook the submit event of the form but when i filled out name and click submit. It won't continue with form submit, somehow it focus on name field again?

Comment: sorry, it works now. I forgot to put action="process.php" in the form tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the submit [function](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#name').focus(); 
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var name = $('#name'); 
    var error_message = $('.error_message'); 
    if (name.val() == '') { 
        title.focus();
        error_message.html('Name is required!');
        e.preventDefault(); // stop submitting the form
    }
});});
```